# C# increment days

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have done a method named nextDay which should increment the day when a user types in a date within the console. The method also changes the year according to what is entered and changes the month. E.g. if I enter within my console 13/10/2012 I want the output to be 14/10/2012 and I want this according to months and year. Any way I could implement this or fix my current method in order for this output to work? At the moment my program is working fine and only retrieves the date the user types in and also does error checking. What I am specifically asking for is to get the next day prior to what the user enters.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace date
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t\tNextDate Application\n\t\t\t\t\t-------------------------------------"); // title

            Console.WriteLine("This application will allow you to enter a valid date and this will get the next day.\n"); // intro of what the application does

            Console.WriteLine("please enter date as dd/MM/yyyy\n"); // tells user to input a date in the formats
            int day; // sets variable
            int month; // sets variable
            int year; // sets variable

            string[] read = Console.ReadLine().Split('/');  // "/" can be read from each value and sets new array
            day = int.Parse(read[0]); // day is first position in array
            month = int.Parse(read[1]); // month is second position in array
            year = int.Parse(read[2]); // year is third position in array

            try
            {
                Date date = new Date(day, month, year); // initialises a new date class
                Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", date.Day, date.Month, date.Year); // given to user as "day/month/year"
                Console.ReadLine(); // reads the line
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message); // states the message for ArgumentOutOfRangeException
                Console.Read(); // breaks
            }     
        }
        class Date
        {
            private int _month; // 1-12
            private int _day; // 1-31 depending on month
            private int _year; // sets the year

            public Date(int day, int month, int year)
            {
                Month = month;
                Day = day;         
                Year = year;
            }

            public void nextDay()
            {
                try
                {
                    _day = _day++;
                }
                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    if (_month == 12) // e.g if month dec 31st then it does a try 
                    {
                        _month = 1; // month then = 1
                        _year++; // year increments
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        _month++; 
                    }
                    _day = 1;
                }

            }

            public int Year
            {
                get { return _year; }
                set
                {
                    if (value >= 1820 && value <= 2020) // if value is higher than or equal to 1820 and less than or equal to 2020
                        _year = value; // sets year as value
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Year must be between 1820 and 2020"); // throws an exception
                }
            }

            public int Month
            {
                get { return _month; }
                set
                {
                    if (value > 0 && value <= 12) // if value is higher than 0 and less than or equal to 12
                        _month = value; // sets month as value
                    else 
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Month must be between 1-12"); // throws an exception
                }
            }

            public int Day
            {
                get { return _day; }
                set
                {
                    int[] days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 }; // array of days of max each month

                    if (value > 0 && value <= days[_month]) // if value is higher than 0 and less than or equal to days of month
                        _day = value; // sets day as value

                    else if (_month == 2 && value == 29 && // else if month is equal to 2 and value is equal to 29
                        _year % 400 == 0 || (_year % 4 == 0 && _year % 100 != 0)) 
                        _day = value;
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Day is out of range"); // throws an exception
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to implement your own Date handling? Did DateTime let you down, or is this an academic exercise?

Comment: You forgot to tell us how your current implementation *doesn't* work as expected.  Is there an error?  Unexpected output?  When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: The date is working fine but when I enter a date I want the next day. This is for experimentation purposes and I want to play around with c#

Comment: @ramteen1993: Ok, where do you *try to calculate* the "next day"?  If you're doing this for academic reasons, asking us to do it for you kind of defeats the purpose.  If you want someone to do it for you, the `DateTime` object already does.

Comment: to get the nextDay while keeping an eye on Month and Year the best way is `date.AddDays(1)` then format as you want. like `date.AddDays(1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: Did you mean to do `Day++;` in your `nextDay` method?

Comment: I am calculating the next day in my nextday method which I have already mentioned in the question.

Comment: @juharr I have already done a Day++ within my nextDay method and this is in my try statement

Comment: @ramteen1993: All you're doing in that method is adding 1 to the "day" value.  Date math is *slightly* more complex than that.  (For example, today is not "January 323rd")

Comment: @ramteen1993 No you're doing `_day++` which isn't going to kick of the logic in your `Day` property.  Also `_day = _day++;` isn't going to do what you think it does. That code will actually leave `_day` unchanged.

Comment: _"to get the next day prior to what the user enters"_ -- "prior" means **"before"**, which would mean _subtracting_ a day, not adding it. Which do you actually mean. Though, a quick look at the documentation for the `DateTime` struct would have answered whatever question you actually have anyway.

Comment: See also [How to add day to date in Linq to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1227648) and [Is there any easy way to increment a DateTime by monthly/yearly/daily units...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1498431), or [any of the 600+ other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+add+day+to+date).

Answer (score 0):

The pragmatic answer:

```
public Date AddDay()
{
    var tomorrow = new DateTime(this._year, this._month, this._year).AddDays(1).Date;
    return new Date(tomorrow.Day, tomorrow.Month, tomorrow.Year);
}
```

or if you prefer mutation

```
public void AddDay()
{
    var tomorrow = new DateTime(this._year, this._month, this._day).AddDays(1).Date;
    this._day = tomorrow.Day;
   //etc...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime theDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime tomorrow = NextDay(theDateTime);
        Console.WriteLine($"Now: {theDateTime:yy/MM/dd}\t\tTomorrow:" +
            $"{tomorrow:yy/MM/dd}");
    }

    private static DateTime NextDay(DateTime source)
    {
        return source + new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Adapt to your code as needed.  Parse input to date time.  Use method.  Parse output accordingly.

Comment: c# 6.0 touch.. hahaha good try

Comment: Down voter care to comment?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that all your logic is in your properties, but in your `nextDay` method you are incrementing the local fields instead.  On top of that the following will result in no change.

```
_day = _day++;
```

because that is equivalent to

```
int temp = _day;
_day = _day + 1;
_day = temp;
```